# How to access AMP.state in a React Component

Tags: reactjs, amp-html

I'm trying to create an AMP compatible component that will show additional content when a button is clicked:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyButton = (props) => {

return (
  <div>
    <amp-state id="showHiddenContent" show="false"></amp-state>
    <amp-bind-macro id="showHiddenContentValue" expression="showHiddenContent.value"></amp-bind-macro>
    {!showHiddenContentValue && (
      <button type="button" on="tap:AMP.setState({showHiddenContent: true})">
        Show More
      </button>
      )}
      {showHiddenContentValue && (
      <div>
        <p>Additional content goes here</p>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
 );
};

export default MyButton;
```

I'm getting a compile time error that says

> 'showHiddenContentValue' is not defined

How can I access the AMP State to make the following conditional statement work?

Comment: where is AMP state components? and where `showHiddenContentValue` value defined?

Comment: I've updated the code to show where 'showHiddenContentValue' comes from. And I am not familiar with AMP state components? Apologies I've fairly new to AMP!

Comment: do you using `react-amphtml` libarary?

Comment: not currently..

Comment: then `amp-html` directly with `react`?

Comment: I do not understand how the library would help, please elaborate

Comment: In general, it is possible to use React with AMP HTML, but it requires additional setup and may not be as straightforward as using React for traditional web development.

Comment: If you using AMP HTML then you don't need react at all or wice-versa. Bcoz same functionality done with tags properties only in AMP HTML. Where as in react we require state and hooks.

Comment: Yes thanks, but I have to make my react code compatible for AMP HTML

Comment: Then start using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-amphtml . With your new react applications.